# How can I improve my algorithm? Degree of divisibility question

Tags: java, algorithm

Hey guys I will explain the question below.

keys = list of integers
I have to find max degree of divisibility of elements in keys. But When I calculate the degree of divisibility I should just consider the keys element. for example:

```
 keys = [2,4,8,2]
 2 = [2,2] degree of divisibility is 2
 4 = [2,4,2] degree of divisibility is 3
 8 = [2,4,8,2] degree of divisibility is 4 so we choose 8 with 4 degrees of divisibility.
```

after that we have to calculate

```
 if maxDegreeOfDivisibility(4 in our case) * 10^5 < validityPeriod* instructionCount then its 
 true.
```

and we return 1 and 4*10^5. I hope I explain the question if u guys have any questions about the question :D I can answer.

```
public static List<Integer> encryptionValidity(int instructionCount, int validityPeriod, 
List<Integer> keys) {
List<Integer> result = Arrays.asList(0, 0);
Map<Integer, Integer> degreeOfDivisibilityCache = new HashMap<>();

for (int i: keys) {
    Integer degreeOfDivisibility = degreeOfDivisibilityCache.getOrDefault(i, -1);

    if (degreeOfDivisibility == -1) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j : keys) {
            if (j > 0 && i % j == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        degreeOfDivisibilityCache.put(i, count);
    }
}

int maxDegreeOfDivisibility = degreeOfDivisibilityCache.values().stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue)).orElse(0);
int s = maxDegreeOfDivisibility * 10000;
result.set(1, s);

BigInteger ic = BigInteger.valueOf(instructionCount);
BigInteger a = ic.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(validityPeriod));
if (a.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(s)) > 0) {
    result.set(0, 1);
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: How many numbers do you expect to be working with?

Comment: Is there a limit for the maximum integer in the list?

Comment: no there is no limit for that

Comment: To get a better running time, we need more info about the max size and distribution of keys. Are there a lot of duplicates? How does the max key compare to the max size of your list? You can't improve on the n^2 worst case time unless you use info about the prime factorization of your keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare 32 buckets, each signifying an integer's most significant bit
2. Scan through the keys, record their occurrence count and put *unique* instances in their respective buckets (unsorted), and flag as candidate
3. Scan the buckets, in descending order of the most significant bit it represents. Compare *only* with contents of buckets of lower bits.

   - 3.1 On a divisible match, aggregate current count with occurrence count in step 2 & clear that number's candidacy flag
   - 3.2 If current count > current record holder, set record holder = this key & current count

Example: [19, 4, 12, 6, 4, 3, 8]

- Occurrences: {19: 1, 4: 2, 12: 1, 6: 1, 3: 1, 8: 1}
- Bucket #16: [19*]
- Bucket #8: [12*, 8*]
- Bucket #4: [4*, 6*]
- Bucket #2: [3*]

1. Scan 19 => 1(self); set record: (19, 1)
2. Scan 12 => 1(self) + 2(from 4) + 1(from 6) + 1(from 3) = 5; clear 4, 6, 3; set record: (12, 5)
3. Scan 8 => 2
4. Skip 4, 6, 3

Time Complexity: if *n* is total integer count and *m* is number of unique integers, O(n) + O(m^2) in BigO notation, but actually O(n) + C*(m^2)/3 (for some constant C)

Analysis:

First scan in step 1: O(n)

Bucket scan: Worst case (full buckets) is inverted binary tree.
This is an infinite series that sums to 1/3 (See related Wikipedia articles: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/4_%2B_1/16_%2B_1/64_%2B_1/256_%2B_%E2%8B%AF))

Credits to Rick James for candidate flag idea.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort the numbers, largest first.  Flag each one as being a candidate.
2. For each number that is still a candidate:
   2.1. Count how many of the numbers after it divide into it.  Mark each such number as no longer a candidate.
3. Search the list for the largest count from step 2.1.  That count is the Degree of Divisibility of the original list.

Example:

1. [2,4,8,2,3,6] (before sorting)
2. [8*,6*,4*,3*,2*,2*]  -- '*' means "is a candidate"

- check 8: [8*,6*,4,3*,2,2] -- divisible by 4 (8,4,2,2)
- check 6: [8*,6*,4,3,2,2] -- divisible by 4 (6,3,2,2)
- the rest don't need checking

3. The answer is 4.

Comment: is this method change bigO() ? I am not sure about that.

Comment: The sort forces it to be at least O(N*logN).  The rest is technically O(N*N), but because most numbers are eliminated along the way, N*N is pessimistic.

Comment: So nothing changes as bigO. My solution has the same bigO aswell

Comment: Actually, this way is more faster then your current way. It remove all unnecessary steps with the help of sort. So you can take short time/steps as much as possible, maxDegreeOfDivisibility value often visible in the head of sorted array. Ideal case, Big(O) = N Log(N), Worst case Big(O) = N * N.

Comment: @huy - Please clarify.  These seem to point to the same algorithm:  "this way" and "your current way".